# What is the point of the saying this parameter belongs to this class?

Tags: php, oop

When we send a class as parameter, we're saying that this parameter belongs to this class like below:

```
// $request is an instance of Request class
public function __construct(Request $request)
{
    $this->request = $request;
}
```

But I don't understand purpose of this, this is a class not an interface, so why we do that?

Comment: Oh boy. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/267246/how-did-oop-evolve-to-include-the-notion-of-properties and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_(programming)

Comment: I'm not good with dependency injection, but this sounds like it's DI. So you don't need to inject Request to every action in that controller, and simply access that `$request` property available within the class. (I'm assuming you're using laravel).

Comment: @Loek Both links you mentioned have nothing to do with what OP asked. Re-read the question.

Comment: @Xatenev That is true. Entire books have been written about this exact question, so it's not really feasible to give a concise answer.

Comment: @IsThisJavascript Wouldn't that still work exactly the same way if he passed in `construct($request)` without specifying the class type?

Comment: Yes @Lewis sorry after reading Script47's reply I see that I misunderstood the question ! :D

Comment: @Xatenev I thought the softwareengineering link was pretty useful, but then it apparently turned out the question was about dependency injection and why you should type that. Didn't make that up from the question. Thought the OP asked why we would declare properties at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Among other reasons this is a sort of type hint and it forces developers to pass an instance of that class rather than anything else:

```
Class T {
  public function test()
  {
    return 'test';
  }
}

class Y {
  public function test(T $t)
  {
    return $t->test();
  }
}

(new Y())->test('test'); // type error 
(new Y())->test(new T()); // no error
```

As per the documentation:

> Type declarations allow functions to require that parameters are of a certain type at call time. If the given value is of the incorrect type, then an error is generated: in PHP 5, this will be a recoverable fatal error, while PHP 7 will throw a TypeError exception.
>
> To specify a type declaration, the type name should be added before the parameter name. The declaration can be made to accept NULL values if the default value of the parameter is set to NULL.

**Live Example**

[Repl](https://repl.it/repls/UselessEarnestCylinders) - Comment out respectively when testing.

**Reading Material**

[Type Declaration](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration)

[Understanding Dependency Injection](http://php-di.org/doc/understanding-di.html)

Comment: Oooooh - is *that* what the OP was asking about, I was wondering :)

Answer (score 1):

A class defines what an object looks like. It has properties (things it knows) and methods (things it can do). For instance, a person object with name age and height:

```
<?php

class Person
{
   private $name;
   private $height;
   private $age;

   public function __construct($name, $height, $age)
   {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->height = $height;
        $this->age = $age;
   }

   public function getName()
   {
        return $this->name;
   }

   public function getAge()
   {
         return $this->age;
   }

   public function getHeight()
   {
         return $this->height;
   }
}

$bob = new Person('Bob', 6, 50);
$alice = new Person('Alice', 5.4, 22);
$tom = new Person('Tom', 5, 30);

$people = [$bob, $alice, $tom];

foreach ($people as $person) {
    echo 'Hi, I\'m ' . $person->getName() . ', I am ' . $person->getHeight() . 'ft tall and ' . $person->getAge() .' years old.' ."\n";
}
```

The output from this is:

```
Hi, I'm Bob, I am 6ft tall and 50 years old. 
Hi, I'm Alice, I am 5.4ft tall and 22 years old. 
Hi, I'm Tom, I am 5ft tall and 30 years old.
```

Essentially, when you pass in arguments into the constructor, you then assign them to the properties, after which you access them using the getter methods. Try adding setter methods too!

Have a play with it here https://3v4l.org/v9Wr4

When you declare a CLASS as a parameter, like this:

```
public function __construct(DateTime $date)
```

You are refusing to just take any old variable, and instead demand that you can only pass in a DateTime object. It's pretty simple :-)

Comment: I'm not sure how this addresses the question.

Comment: This is exactly why I commented my links. I thought OP was asking why we would declare properties at all. Maybe he should edit the question so it's more clear?

Comment: @Loek actually I'm new at programming and I don't have enough information about what are typehints or uniform access principle etc.. as I mentioned at the question, I had no idea about why we saying this and now I start to understand,  thanks both of you, your answers and suggested documents